# In My Project i have x_user_module_perm table for which i need to keep one primary key and one composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using a syntax :-

```
CREATE TABLE `x_user_module_perm` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`module_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`create_time` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`update_time` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`added_by_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`upd_by_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`is_allowed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`module_id`),
KEY `x_user_module_perm_idx_module_id` (`module_id`),
KEY `x_user_module_perm_idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `x_user_module_perm_FK_module_id` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `x_modules_master` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `x_user_module_perm_FK_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `x_portal_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;
```

I am getting a error cannot use two primary key's

Do is it possible, Guy's please Guide me !!!

Comment: As the error says, you cannot have two primary keys

Comment: Why not use id as part of composite key `PRIMARY KEY (id,user_id,module_id),`

Comment: no Abhik chakraborty there might i thought of doing that but we can have entrie (1,2,5) (2,2,5) (3,2,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `PRIMARY KEY (user_id,module_id)` to `UNIQUE INDEX(user_id,module_id)`

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry I changed back my code, but both are possible to use :)